# Identify a comic where Bruce Wayne did not change to Batman throughout the issue

Tags: dc, comics, batman

Is there any comic book where Bruce did not put his batsuit on, and fought with gangsters/thugs as himself, without changing into Batman ?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the 'story-ident' or 'episode-ident' tag is necessary here

Comment: Those tags are for use identifying a property that is known to exist. The OP is asking for a list of works that match his criteria.

Comment: I've voted to close. The answer below clearly shows that this has happened on *multiple occasions* over the last 70 years.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. They're not asking for a complete list, but whether or not this has already happened. One example should be sufficient.

Comment: @tobiasvl - The answer suggests that this is a common happenstance rather than a rarity. You might as well ask when Buffy's killed a vampire

Answer (score 8):

Bruce fights pimps, prostitutes, and Selina Kyle in street clothes in Batman #404, 1987
Bruce beats up a gang Bialyan thugs in a tuxedo in Justice League International #16, 1988
Bruce briefly fights with Batman(Jean Paul Valley) in Robin #7, 1994

[image: Batman #404]

[image: Batman #404 part 2[![][2][2]][image]

Comment: Can you offer any panels to back this up?

Comment: Certainly, the fight in Justice League International #16 takes place on page 17 an occurs in panels 2-7.

Comment: Awesome. I was hoping for some screenshots or scans though...

Comment: Image 1 and 2 are from Batman #404. Image 3 is from Robin #7. Image 4 is from Justice League International #16.

Comment: Nicely done. Much better.